# How might I index PDF files using Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net, implementation

I'm looking for some sample code demonstrating how to index PDF documents using Lucene.Net and C#. Google turned up a few, but none that I could find helpful.

Comment: I'm a *nerd*, thank you very much.

Comment: You see, I prefer the term geek... :)

Comment: Some overlap with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83152/reading-pdf-documents-in-net or more precisely this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83152/reading-pdf-documents-in-net/84410#84410

Answer (score 6):

From my understanding, Lucene is limited to creating an index and searching that index.  It's up to the application to handle opening files and extracting their contents for the index.  So if you're looking to search PDF documents you'll want to use something like [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to open the file, pull out the contents, and pass it to Lucene for indexing.  There are some good starting examples of using Lucene on the [Dimecasts.net](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/Lucene) website.

Comment: That is a possible solution ... needs practical proof that it actually works.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(byte[] of the .pdf);

for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page) + " ");
}
```

(using iTextSharp)

The rest isn't as succinctly illustrated.

There is code in the product demo on my site that shows how to use the lucene.net code, but it is a little long to post here.

Here is the code as pertaining to my product: https://svn.arachnode.net/svn/arachnodenet/trunk/Plugins/CrawlActions/ManageLuceneDotNetIndexes.cs  Username/Password: Public