# Prepare doc and docx Files for Lucene indexing

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

I wanted to ask if there is a quick way of getting content of a document into a single document field. All the examples i have seen have relatively short strings. I cannot save an entire journal article into a string and indexthat is there a quick way of telling lucene to index all the words in a file? I am using Lucene.net 3.03 for this application.

Comment: Could use iFilter to extract words.  You get words with no formatting.  Paid there is Aspose for formatted text.

Comment: What is the format of the document and what do you mean by journal article?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to pass just the file, you have to provide the entire content to lucene to made the indexing for the search. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275722/how-might-i-index-pdf-files-using-lucene-net) is a answer from the Q/A about indexing PDF, but is the same from every type of document, just open it and index to lucene.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass a `System.IO.TextReader` to a `Field`.  If the file is plain text, or something like it, you should just be able to open the Reader on it, and pass it directly into the Field, like:

```
System.IO.TextReader reader = new StreamReader("path/to/my/file.txt");
Field field = new Field("fieldName", reader);
document.add(field);
```

Comment: I like this idea!!! Are readers availabe in C# if so what namespace do I need to reference?

Comment: That's my best shot at the C# version.  Not really a C# dev, to be honest, so if I messed something up, please feel free to edit.