# how to prevent caching PDF's locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, webforms

I have an asp.net webform that displays a PDF, Stack helped me with that [How to display a pdf file in asp.net web-form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5083893/456532).  My problem now is that this seems to cache the PDF files locally.  I need them to be freshly retrieved from the server each time they're called to account for updates.

The PDF files are stored in a network shared folder.

How can I prevent these files from caching in code (or do I have to do from IIS or the shared folder)?

Comment: You _could_ do the poor man's hack and always append a get string of the current datetime of the request, in javascript time (so milliseconds)

Comment: @jcolebrand -Yuck!  I really hope there's a better way...

Comment: There is, I just said "you _could_ do poor man's caching prevention"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with below code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
}
```

Comment: If you are using .NET 3.5 or higher add `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);` also.

Comment: What will so in terms of any difference between these two statements in any context...? Your ideas are highly appreciated..

Comment: @JamieSee -This isn't doing the trick.  I have a user complaining about this who is using Google Chrome browser.  Is there anything additional/different I can do to improve this?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in Chrome. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28035 for more information.