# Reading PDF Text Images in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, text

I need to read the pdf file and need to convert to HTML. Currently I'm using iTextsharp to read PDF. Is there any dll with proper documentation to **read pdf files**.

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295555/how-to-convert-pdf-into-html-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

ITextSharp is pretty decent and quite easy to implement.. Here is a small example of reading a pdf and putting the text into a string which is then printed out to a label on a webforms page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace pdfreadertest
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetTextFromPDFFile(@"c:\example.pdf", 1);
        }

        public void GetTextFromPDFFile(string pdfFile, int pageNumber)
        {
            // Call the reader to read the pdf file
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);

            // Extract the text from the pdf reader and put into a string
            string pdfText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pageNumber);

            // Try and close the reader
            try
            {
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
            catch{ }

            // Put the string (pdf text) into a label to display on page
            this.lblPdfText.Text = pdfText;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming to this question in 2023, you can read text from PDFs with C# (NET Core) with something like this. This is possible with the `itext7` nuget package. (A link to a working solution containing this code can be found [here](https://www.debugandrelease.com/how-to-scan-a-pdf-for-text-using-csharp/)).

```cs
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;

namespace ScanTextInPDFs
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string executingDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

            byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync($"{executingDirectory}PDFs\\Brochure.pdf");
            string textToFind = "Lorem ipsum";
            bool foundText = false;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                using PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(memoryStream);
                using PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
                {
                    PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(page);
                    string pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfPage, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

                    if (pageText.Contains(textToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        foundText = true;
                }
            }

            if (foundText)
                Console.WriteLine($"Found '{textToFind}' in the pdf.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Did not find '{textToFind}' in the pdf.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think iTextSharp is one of the most popular even though there are several other libs like 
iText.Net, PDF Sharp, Sharp PDF etc 
Google it, you will find a lot of them. I have used iTextSharp and i like it.

Comment: The OP said he is using iTextsharp already, so could you please elaborate what your answer is about?