# Reading PDF content with itextsharp dll in VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, itext

How can I read PDF content with the itextsharp with the Pdfreader class. My PDF may include Plain text or Images of  the text.

Comment: iTextSharp is now called "iText 7 for .NET"or "itext7-dotnet" on github:  [link](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet). It's recommended to add itext7 with Nuget to your solution.

Answer (score 193):

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.IO;

public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason the pdfReader.Close(); happens inside the for loop?

Comment: why using .Close() at all and not `using (var pdfReader = ...) {}`

Comment: Also, `ASCIIEncoding.Convert` should be `Encoding.Convert` as it is a static method

Answer (score 17):

## LGPL / FOSS iTextSharp 4.x

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(path); //other filestream etc
byte[] pageContent = _pdfReader .GetPageContent(pageNum); //not zero based
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, pageContent);
string textFromPage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8);
```

None of the other answers were useful to me, they all seem to target the AGPL v5 of iTextSharp. I could never find any reference to `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` or `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` in the FOSS version.

Something else that might be very useful in conjunction with this:

```
const string PdfTableFormat = @"\(.*\)Tj";
Regex PdfTableRegex = new Regex(PdfTableFormat, RegexOptions.Compiled);

List<string> ExtractPdfContent(string rawPdfContent)
{
    var matches = PdfTableRegex.Matches(rawPdfContent);

    var list = matches.Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value
            .Substring(1) //remove leading (
            .Remove(m.Value.Length - 4) //remove trailing )Tj
            .Replace(@"\)", ")") //unencode parens
            .Replace(@"\(", "(")
            .Trim()
        )
        .ToList();
    return list;
}
```

This will extract the text-only data from the PDF if the text displayed is `Foo(bar)` it will be encoded in the PDF as `(Foo\(bar\))Tj`, this method would return `Foo(bar)` as expected. This method will strip out lots of additional information such as location coordinates from the raw pdf content.

Comment: You are right, before 5.x.x text extraction was present in iText merely as proof-of-concept and in iTextSharp not at all. That being said, the code you present only works in very primitively built PDFs (using fonts with an ASCII'ish encoding and **Tj** as only text drawing operator). It may be usable in very controlled environments (in which you can ensure to only get such primitive PDFs) but not in general.

Comment: The correct Regex expression is: (?<=\()(.*?)(?=\) Tj)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a VB.NET solution based on ShravankumarKumar's solution.

This will ONLY give you the text.  The images are a different story.

```
Public Shared Function GetTextFromPDF(PdfFileName As String) As String
    Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileName)

    Dim sOut = ""

    For i = 1 To oReader.NumberOfPages
        Dim its As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy

        sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, i, its)
    Next

    Return sOut
End Function
```

Comment: When I try this on my PDF, it gives me the error message, "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value". Any idea what this is about?

Comment: sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, i, its). 

Also, I figured something out about this error. If I take it out of the loop and parse the individual pages, it works on one page and not the other. The only difference between the two that I can tell is that the problematic page has images on it (which I don't need).

Comment: If you'd like to have a look at the PDF, I can send it to you.

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.0 and itextsharp 5.1.2.0 (Just downloaded).  Same with you?

Comment: .Net 3.5 and itextsharp 5.1.1. I'll update and see if it's resolved.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I just wanted the text from a specific area of the PDF document so I used a rectangle around the area and extracted the text from it.  In the sample below the coordinates are for the entire page.  I don't have PDF authoring tools so when it came time to narrow down the rectangle to the specific location I took a few guesses at the coordinates until the area was found.

```
Rectangle _pdfRect = new Rectangle(0f, 0f, 612f, 792f); // Entire page - PDF coordinate system 0,0 is bottom left corner.  72 points / inch
RenderFilter _renderfilter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(_pdfRect);
ITextExtractionStrategy _strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), _filter);
string _text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(_pdfReader, 1, _strategy);
```

As noted by the above comments the resulting text doesn't maintain any of the formatting found in the PDF document, however, I was happy that it did preserve the carriage returns.  In my case, there were enough constants in the text that I was able to extract the values that I required.

Answer (score 1):

Here an improved answer of ShravankumarKumar. I created special classes for the pages so you can access words in the pdf based on the text rows and the word in that row.

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

//create a list of pdf pages
var pages = new List<PdfPage>();

//load the pdf into the reader. NOTE: path can also be replaced with a byte array
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
{
    //loop all the pages and extract the text
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        pages.Add(new PdfPage()
        {
           content = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i)
        });
    }
}

//use linq to create the rows and words by splitting on newline and space
pages.ForEach(x => x.rows = x.content.Split('\n').Select(y => 
    new PdfRow() { 
       content = y,
       words = y.Split(' ').ToList()
    }
).ToList());
```

The custom classes

```
class PdfPage
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public List<PdfRow> rows { get; set; }
}


class PdfRow
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public List<string> words { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can get a word by row and word index.

```
string myWord = pages[0].rows[12].words[4];
```

Or use Linq to find the rows containing a specific word.

```
//find the rows in a specific page containing a word
var myRows = pages[0].rows.Where(x => x.words.Any(y => y == "myWord1")).ToList();

//find the rows in all pages containing a word
var myRows = pages.SelectMany(r => r.rows).Where(x => x.words.Any(y => y == "myWord2")).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Public Sub PDFTxtToPdf(ByVal sTxtfile As String, ByVal sPDFSourcefile As String)
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(sTxtfile)
    Dim doc As New Document()
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(sPDFSourcefile, FileMode.Create))
    doc.Open()
    doc.Add(New Paragraph(sr.ReadToEnd()))
    doc.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Question is asking to read a PDF file, your answer is creating one!