# Find and mark text occurrence in a PDF using C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I would like to parse a given pdf and add a circle when I find a certain text occurence. Highlighting would be even better. I read it is [not possible with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550796/reading-pdf-content-with-itextsharp-dll-in-vb-net-or-c/2554230#2554230).

Do you know any library I could use ?

Comment: Have you checked out the links on the answer you link to?  Seems there are links to lots of resources for reading PDFs in C#.

Comment: Your question in answered here:http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201308/find-and-mark-text-occurrence-in-a-pdf-using-c-38192.html