# itextsharp and pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i want to read a pdf file line per line but i want to maintain his original format

¿can i do this with itextsharp?

i use the next code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string text = string.Empty;
            string path = string.Empty;
            path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Rafael\\Desktop\\Imprimiendo\\Print1.pdf";
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
                richTextBox1.Text = text;

            }
            reader.Close();
            return;
        }
```

thanks, i really need your help

Comment: What do you mean by reading a PDF file line per line? And the format of what do you want to maintain? In your sample code you use a text extractor which only extracts text, nothing else, especially no format Information. Not so long  agohere had been some talk about rich text extraction strategies....

Comment: I need to read a pdf file but with the original format , i dont know a lot about itextsharp thats the reason why i need  help

Comment: What 'format' do you mean? Do you mean font and style information? Or do you mean the order of the words, e.g. respecting multicolumnar texts?

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632541/get-the-exact-stringposition-in-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read PDF file with small data in it, iTextsharp would be the best choice, you may find answer here:

[Reading PDF content with itextsharp dll in VB.NET or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550796/reading-pdf-content-with-itextsharp-dll-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp)

However, if you have huge data in your PDF file, iTextsharp will have problems in realizing this task. in such a case, you may need a third party library. This article may help you much:

[Read PDF file in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/466394/Extract-and-Remove-PDF-Attachments-with-Csharp)