# Fetch Coordinates of a key in a pdf rendered via itext

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, digital-signature

I have a pdf document in form of `ByteArrayOutputStream` rendered via iText using velocity engine, now I want to place a digital signature in a specified region for which i would require the coordinates of that region.

Is there any way in Java where I could find the coordinates of the particular string such as "DigitalSignature" and embed the signature on top of this.

Comment: What you need to do is something like text extraction with coordinates. You can do that e.g. with itext. There are many questions and answers here on stack overflow on that subject.

Comment: Did the comment help? Or have you lost interest in the topic? Or are you still interested but don't know how to proceed?

Comment: @mkl thanks for the comment, finally found the solution

Comment: Future visitors of your question on this site might be curious about your solution...

Comment: The solution is already on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632541/get-the-exact-stringposition-in-pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the exact Stringposition in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632541/get-the-exact-stringposition-in-pdf)