# Reading and extracting information from pdf or word file using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, openxml-sdk, text-extraction

I want to build an application that read and extract information from a pdf or word file.
For example I have a file either in pdf format or in word format and I want to extract information like contact, address, email etc. How I can do it using c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Word just have a look at the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) and the [Power Tools for Open XML](https://powertools.codeplex.com). They give you the possibility to work with any Open XML File very smoothly.
For PDFs just have a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) which is an awesome PDF library for .Net.

Comment: I have tried iTextSharp but not working for me :(. @Rafeel Regh

Comment: Then be more specific. What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: I have tried this 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5003230/4913418)

Comment: I don't need to see the link, I need to see what your **actual** problem is. Tell me what is not working, what you have tried and where it stuck.

Comment: Kindly check the link I am using that code. It's not opening my pdf file.

Comment: I did and it is running **perfectly** without any changes. That's why **you** have to provide more detailed information. What is your setup (win forms, wf, etc)? What is the **exact** problem? Do you get an exception? Is it not compiling etc. pp

Comment: My setup is win forms. I am passing the filename from textbox text and when I ran it game exception no file found. But file is there I selected it through open file dialogue box. @Rafeel Regh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85078/discussion-between-muhammad-hannan-and-rafael-regh).