# Ready An Existing PDF Page Size (ex. 8.5 x 11, 11 x 17) VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, sizeof, acrobat

Like the title says i'd like to read an existing pdf page size with VB.Net.  I've been working with Itext.Sharp, and the Acrobat.dll.  Is this possible??

Comment: This post will hopefully put you on the right track. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83152/reading-pdf-documents-in-net

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different "Boxes" a given page can have:

Media Box (required): The initial page size when printing viewing.
Crop Box (optional): Supersedes the media box.  Defaults to match the media box.  Must be a subset or match the media box.

There's also art/trim/bleed boxes, but they don't matter as much and are much less common.

So, the page size:

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(myPath);
   // gets the MEDIA BOX
   Rectangle pageRect = reader.getPageSize(1); // 1 -> first page

// gets the crop box if present, or the media box if not.
   Rectangle cropRect = reader.getCropBox(1);

// and finally
   Rectangle artBox = reader.getBoxSize( 1, "art");
   // could be "art", "bleed", "crop", "media", or "trim"

I'd go with `getCropBox()`.

I also recommend checking out the JavaDoc for things like this.  At the very least you would have come up with `getPageSize()` on your own.  No, it's not C#.  Yes, it's very useful.

http://api.itextpdf.com/

Also note that these Rectangles need not be based on 0,0 (which would be the lower left corner on an unrotated page).

Further, you should check the page's rotation, `getPageRotation(int)`, and swap height and width if the rotation is 90 or 270.  There is `getPageSizeWithRotation(int)`, but it only works with the media box, so I'd do it yourself if I were you.  It's only a few extra lines of code:

```
// rotation has to be 0, 90, 180, or 270.  "360" isn't kosher IIRC.
if (reader.getPageRotation(pageNum) % 180 != 0) {
  float tmp = width;
  width = height;
  height = tmp;
}
```