# C# pdf to text converter

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading PDF documents in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83152/reading-pdf-documents-in-net)

Is any free library to render pdf. I need to parse pdf and show images and text separately...
Will be thankful for any information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/

This is the one I've been using..

Comment: From the FAQ: "Can I use PDFsharp to extract text from PDF? 
This can be done at a low level. You can get at the characters in the order they are drawn - and most applications draw them from top-left to bottom-right. There are no high-level functions that return words, paragraphs, or whole pages." I've tried that approach, the output is crap.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). It is a C# port of iText. It is licensed under the AGPL v3. It should be able to pull out the text for you.

Comment: I have this library! Is any examples how to get text or images from pdf?

Comment: Check out the answer here for an image extraction example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802269/itextsharp-extract-images

Comment: iTextSharp (versions after 5.0) may be not that free as one may think. See itextpdf.com/terms-of-use for more info.

Comment: Yes it is definitely important to understand the terms of the AGPLv3. It often requires publishing your source code, among other things, if you wish to use the iText stuff freely.