# Read pdf using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading PDF documents in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83152/reading-pdf-documents-in-net)

How do I read a pdf file using c# .net ? 
I need to extract the text from a pdf file.

Any help is appreciates.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library like ITextSharp http://itextpdf.com/

There has been a similar question on SO in the past, have a look at this

[Reading PDF content with itextsharp dll in VB.NET or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550796/reading-pdf-content-with-itextsharp-dll-in-vb-net-or-c)

Answer (score 0):

I would HIGHLY recommend pdf sharp
See https://stackoverflow.com/users/162529/pdfsharp-team

They're quite active on SO itself.